# how to add BS4 to pyzo2013b?

Tags: python, installation, beautifulsoup, python-3.4

I downloaded and 'installed' pyzo3 in **C:/Program Files (x86)/pyzo2013b**, and I downloaded beautifulsoup 4.4 from here http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/ and unzipped it on my desktop that is **C:/Users/Desktop**.

I tried to adapt what is explained here [here](https://plus.google.com/111697067583215378220/posts/9qtprfoafRe)

> To install you can probably use "C:\pyzo2013b\Scripts\pip.exe install beautifulsoup4".
>
> Otherwise, unzip the .gz somewhere, go to that directory and run "C:\pyzo2013b\python.exe setup.py install".
>
> There is no "install" command inside the IEP shell. Not yet, anyway.

... but I was unsuccessful.

Can anyone throw some light on this? (I'm new to python, I've never added a library, yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this solution works:

- adding Python (C:\ .... \python.exe) to the variable environment
- going to the folder where beautifulsoup4 is unzipped from within the command console
- running "C:\ ... \python.exe" setup.py build   ,  first
- then running "C:\ ... \python.exe" setup.py install